# sending url stream as zip

Tags: java, zip, file-transfer

I want to read a file by urlstream which is not zipped on server, and send it as zipped file. My question is what is the most efficient way or best practise to do this. for instance, is it possible to do this in a streaming way, I mean without saving the content to local disc or in memory first?

Comment: ASAIK, I don't think this is a good idea. You want to zip it right away after it is fully read from the URL stream. what you can do is read the file from *urlstream* and save it in disk. once, it is fully read, you can zip it.

Answer (score 1):

> for instance, is it possible to do this in a streaming way, I mean without saving the content to local disc or in memory first?

Yes. Use a `ZipOutputStream`.

However, the standard HTTP way to do this is to use gzip compression, not zip compression. That way, the user agent can transparently decompress the file at the other end.

Comment: I am sending this stream as web service attachment and using javax.activation.Datahandler for this. So is your answer using gzip still applicable ?

Comment: HTTP can send anything gzipped, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Http is using gzip compression. Using `ZipOutputStream` is a little more complicated than `GZIPOutputStream` because zip files are containers that can contain multiple files.

Since you are looking for efficient way, that will not use too much memory good solution is also [FlushableGZIPOutputStream](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/coyote/http11/filters/FlushableGZIPOutputStream.html) which is:

> extension of GZIPOutputStream to workaround for a couple of long
>   standing JDK bugs (Bug 4255743 and Bug 4813885) so the GZIP'd output
>   can be flushed.